# Missing previous month data

Tags: data-request, api, openfda, data

We are using below mentioned API to fetch data based on product code and date range:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20230927+TO+20231027]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:"OXO"&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20230927+TO+20231027%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22OXO%22&limit=1000)

From the above API response we can clearly see that the API data has been updated on 10-Oct-2023 and therefore it should include all the data/records of the previous month as well ie data for Sep-2023 but it is missing the records of 30-Sep-2023 which are present on -

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/results.cfm.

Also request you to please let us know the frequency of API updated as earlier it says that it updates every week and now it says a monthly update from the below URL.

https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/510k/

Kindly suggest.

Thanks,
Shailendra Jetpuria

Comment: Just a reminder to not include your API key when posting questions online

Comment: I just did a search on the UI for 09/30/2023 as you said in your post. UI does not return any results, either: No records were found with
Report Date From: 09/30/2023 Report Date To: 09/30/2023

Answer (score 0):

The Device Event endpoint updates weekly (typically, over weekends) as mentioned [here](https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/event/).

openFDA builds its Device Event endpoint from the FDA MAUDE data files posted by the FDA on [this page](https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/mandatory-reporting-requirements-manufacturers-importers-and-device-user-facilities/about-manufacturer-and-user-facility-device-experience-maude). Regardless of what the MAUDE Search webpage displays, the data needs to be available within those files in order to be processed by openFDA.

Let me force a Device Event update in openFDA now and see what I can find out about the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this, the MAUDE Search page does *not* return any results for `OXO` for 09/30/2023, either. The most recent one is 9/29/2023: [image]

And we do have those in openFDA as well: [https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20230901+TO+20231027]+AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:OXO&limit=1000&sort=date_received:desc](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20230901+TO+20231027%5D+AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:OXO&limit=1000&sort=date_received:desc)